# Brackets in XPath expressions in SeleniumIDE

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-ide

I have a problem with SeleniumIDE's evaulation of XPath. SeleniumIDE seems to not know the round brackets in this xpath:

```
(//span[@class='section-name entry-box'])[last()]/input
```

It cannot find even this xpath:

```
(//span[@class='section-name entry-box'])[last()]
```

or

```
(//span[@class='section-name entry-box'])/input
```

But in FireFox FireBug console or in FireFox plugin XPather, all the xpaths works and finds one (or in the last example two) elements on the page.

Do you know any solution? I need to choose last element, which has specific class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put "xpath=" at the beginning.  Selenium locators can be a variety of different types, and Selenium assumes the type is XPath if the locator starts with "//".  Your's doesn't, so you need to specify it explicitly.